# AS3 Calculator?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am in the process of creating a calculator entirely through actionscript, nothing is on the staging area. So far i am up to performing the calculations. However i seem to be having problems. A sample of my code is shown below:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var btn:Array = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
var myBtn:Btn = new Btn();
myBtn.y = 15;
myBtn.x = i * 100 + 15;
myBtn.width = 48;
myBtn.height = 48;
myBtn.buttonMode = true;
myBtn.mouseChildren = false;
myBtn.num = Number(i);
myBtn.caption.text = String (i);
addChild(myBtn);
btn.push(myBtn);
btn[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pressNumber);//EVENT TO ADD NUMBERS TO     DISPLAY 

}
btn[0].y += 370;
btn[0].x += 10;

btn[1].y += 310;
btn[1].x += -90;

btn[2].y += 310;
btn[2].x += -130;

btn[3].y += 310;
btn[3].x += -170;

btn[4].y += 250;
btn[4].x += -390;

btn[5].y += 250;
btn[5].x += -430;

btn[6].y += 250;
btn[6].x += -470;

btn[7].y += 190;
btn[7].x += -690;

btn[8].y += 190;
btn[8].x += -730;

btn[9].y += 190;
btn[9].x += -770;

//OPERATORS//
var operators:Array = new Array();
for(var io:int = 0; io < 6; io++) {
var opBtn:Btn_operator = new Btn_operator();
opBtn.width = 48;
opBtn.height = 48;
opBtn.buttonMode = true;
opBtn.mouseChildren = false;
opBtn.caption_op.text = String (".");
addChild(opBtn);
operators.push(opBtn);  
operators[io].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressOperator);//EVENT TO ADD   OPERATORS TO DISPLAY
}

//ADD DOT
var dot:Btn_dot = new Btn_dot();
dot.width = 48;
dot.height = 48;
dot.buttonMode = true;
dot.mouseChildren = false;
dot.caption_op.text = String (".");
addChild(dot);

dot.y += 383;
dot.x += 78;
dot.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addDot);//EVENT TO ADD DOT TO DISPLAY

//BACKSPACE
var goBack:Btn_backspace = new Btn_backspace();
goBack.width = 48;
goBack.height = 48;
goBack.buttonMode = true;
goBack.mouseChildren = false;
goBack.caption_op.text = String ("<--");
addChild(goBack);

goBack.y += 203;
goBack.x += 256;
goBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backSpace);//EVENT TO GO BACK SPACE IN DISPLAY

//BACKSPACE
var clearAll:Btn_clear = new Btn_clear();
clearAll.width = 48;
clearAll.height = 48;
clearAll.buttonMode = true;
clearAll.mouseChildren = false;
clearAll.caption_op.text = String ("C");
addChild(clearAll);


clearAll.y += 323;
clearAll.x += 256;
clearAll.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearFields);//EVENT TO GO BACK SPACE IN   DISPLAY

operators[0].y += 383;
operators[0].x += 138;
operators[0].caption_op.text = String("=");

operators[1].y += 383;
operators[1].x += 198;
operators[1].caption_op.text = String("/");

operators[2].y += 323;
operators[2].x += 198;
operators[2].caption_op.text = String("*");

operators[3].y += 263;
operators[3].x += 198;
operators[3].caption_op.text = String("-");

operators[4].y += 203;
operators[4].x += 198;
operators[4].caption_op.text = String("+");

operators[5].y += 263;
operators[5].x += 256;
operators[5].caption_op.text = String("-/+");


//VARIABLE HANDLE OPERATION NOT BUTTON
var operate:String;

//HANDLE FIRST AND SECOND VALUE
var num1:Number;
var num2:Number;

//grouping all buttons in function


//display_txt.text = "0";
//DISPLAYING NUMBERS IN DISPLAY
//var numberEntered:String ="";
function pressNumber(e:MouseEvent):void{
       display_txt.appendText(e.target.num);
}

//DISPLAY OPERATORS
function pressOperator(event:MouseEvent):void{
var operatorEntered:String;
trace("a",display_txt.text,display_txt.text.length,event.currentTarget.caption_op.t     ext,event.currentTarget.caption_op.text.length);
display_txt.appendText(event.currentTarget.caption_op.text);
//CHECKING FOR VALUES AND STORING NUMBERS
trace("b",display_txt.text);         
if(isNaN(num1)){
    //CONVERT STRING TO NUMBER
    num1=Number(display_txt.text);
    operate = operatorEntered;
    display_txt.text = "";
    //trace(num1,isNaN(num1)); // if this outputs some number and true, display_txt an         html enabled textfield, has kerning enabled or is a multiline textfield.  fix that.
}
else if(isNaN(num2)){
    num2 = Number(display_txt.text);
    //trace(num1,isNaN(num2)); // if this outputs some number and true,        display_txt an html enabled textfield, has kerning enabled or is a multiline textfield.  fix that.
    performCalculation();
    operate = operatorEntered;
}
}


//CLEARS DISPLAY AREA
function clearFields(event:MouseEvent):void{
display_txt.text = "";
num1=NaN;
num2=NaN;
}

//ADDS DECIMAL PLACE
function addDot(event:MouseEvent):void{
if(event.target.num == Number(display_txt.text))
{
display_txt.text = "0";
}
if (display_txt.text.indexOf(".")==-1){
    display_txt.appendText(".");
}

}
//BACKSPACE DISPLAY AREA
function backSpace(e:MouseEvent):void{
var temp_str:String = display_txt.text;
display_txt.text = temp_str.substr(0, (temp_str.length-1)); // Get rid of last      character in the string, which in this case is the phantom \r or \n character
}

function performCalculation():void{

switch (operate){
case "multiply":
    num1*=num2;
break;
case "divide":
    num1/=num2;
break;
case "subtract":
    num1-=num2;
break;
case "add":
    num1+=num2;
break;
    default:
break;
}
//now that we found out the result
//let's display on the window
display_txt.text=String(num1);
num2=NaN;

}
```

It doesn't seem to be performing the calculations and in the code shown below, it is meant to be calling the function to perform the calculations but it doesn't seem to be doing that anymore and when i try to trace num1 it outputs as NaN when it is meant to show the button last pressed when i click on a operator.

```
function pressOperator(event:MouseEvent):void{
var operatorEntered:String;
trace("a",display_txt.text,display_txt.text.length,event.currentTarget.caption_op.t    ext,event.currentTarget.caption_op.text.length);
display_txt.appendText(event.currentTarget.caption_op.text);
//CHECKING FOR VALUES AND STORING NUMBERS
trace("b",display_txt.text);         
if(isNaN(num1)){
    //CONVERT STRING TO NUMBER
    num1=Number(display_txt.text);
    operate = operatorEntered;
    display_txt.text = "";
    //trace(num1,isNaN(num1)); // if this outputs some number and true, display_txt an     html enabled textfield, has kerning enabled or is a multiline textfield.  fix that.
}
else if(isNaN(num2)){
    num2 = Number(display_txt.text);
    //trace(num1,isNaN(num2)); // if this outputs some number and true,     display_txt an html enabled textfield, has kerning enabled or is a multiline textfield.  fix that.
    performCalculation();
    operate = operatorEntered;
}
}
```

I think it is resulting in NaN because nothing is going into the vars for operate and operatorEntered however they are both going into each other. How would I solve that?

Comment: For converting `String->Number` you need `parseInt(str_num)` or `parseFloat(str_num)` methods, not `Number(str_num)`.

Answer (score 1):

This might not directly answer your question but I would really recommend you taking a look on how to write a document class in a "pure" ActionScript 3 project. It will not only force you to "tighten" up your code, if only just slightly. But you could also use a proper IDE (i.e. FlashDevelop which is free) with better debugging features which will help you find your problem easier.

Also if you post code that you want other people to look at, make sure it's well formatted and easy to read (at least indented and preferably with comments). In this case it makes use of things in the FLA file so we can't just copy your code and paste it into our flash either.
All these factors just makes it really hard to help you out.